Apply a function in a data frame group-wise on a subset of rows?
By using tidyverse, I want to calculate standard deviation of alt_freq column grouping by rsid in a data frame. In each group, I want to consider only those rows which have at least 100 samples. I want to avoid creating additional groups.
I get the same result on sdev column for all the filters below:
snps_df %>% group_by(rsid) %>% mutate(sdev = case_when(sample_size >= 0 ~ sd(alt_freq, na.rm = TRUE)))

# A tibble: 610 × 9
# Groups:   rsid [10]
   rsid  study                       population       group      sample_size ref_allele alt_allele         alt_freq       sdev
   <chr> <chr>                       <chr>            <chr>            <dbl> <chr>      <chr>                 <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 rs10  TopMed                      Global           Study-wide      264690 A=0.036027 C=0.963973         0.963973 0.06598503
 2 rs10  14KJPN                      JAPANESE         Study-wide       28258 A=0.00014  C=0.99986          0.99986  0.06598503
 3 rs10  8.3KJPN                     JAPANESE         Study-wide       16758 A=0.00018  C=0.99982          0.99982  0.06598503
 4 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator Total            Global            8536 A=0.0750   C=0.9250, T=0.0000 0.925    0.06598503
 5 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator European         Sub               7346 A=0.0826   C=0.9174, T=0.0000 0.9174   0.06598503
 6 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator African          Sub                676 A=0.006    C=0.994, T=0.000   0.994    0.06598503
 7 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator Other            Sub                484 A=0.052    C=0.948, T=0.000   0.948    0.06598503
 8 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator Latin American 2 Sub                 10 A=0.4      C=0.6, T=0.0       0.6      0.06598503
 9 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator Latin American 1 Sub                  8 A=0.0      C=1.0, T=0.0       1        0.06598503
10 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator Asian            Sub                  8 A=0.0      C=1.0, T=0.0       1        0.06598503
# ℹ 600 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

:
snps_df %>% group_by(rsid) %>% mutate(sdev = case_when(sample_size >= 100 ~ sd(alt_freq, na.rm = TRUE)))

# A tibble: 610 × 9
# Groups:   rsid [10]
   rsid  study                       population       group      sample_size ref_allele alt_allele         alt_freq        sdev
   <chr> <chr>                       <chr>            <chr>            <dbl> <chr>      <chr>                 <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 rs10  TopMed                      Global           Study-wide      264690 A=0.036027 C=0.963973         0.963973  0.06598503
 2 rs10  14KJPN                      JAPANESE         Study-wide       28258 A=0.00014  C=0.99986          0.99986   0.06598503
 3 rs10  8.3KJPN                     JAPANESE         Study-wide       16758 A=0.00018  C=0.99982          0.99982   0.06598503
 4 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator Total            Global            8536 A=0.0750   C=0.9250, T=0.0000 0.925     0.06598503
 5 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator European         Sub               7346 A=0.0826   C=0.9174, T=0.0000 0.9174    0.06598503
 6 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator African          Sub                676 A=0.006    C=0.994, T=0.000   0.994     0.06598503
 7 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator Other            Sub                484 A=0.052    C=0.948, T=0.000   0.948     0.06598503
 8 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator Latin American 2 Sub                 10 A=0.4      C=0.6, T=0.0       0.6      NA         
 9 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator Latin American 1 Sub                  8 A=0.0      C=1.0, T=0.0       1        NA         
10 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator Asian            Sub                  8 A=0.0      C=1.0, T=0.0       1        NA         
# ℹ 600 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

:
snps_df %>% group_by(rsid) %>% mutate(sdev = case_when(sample_size >= 10000 ~ sd(alt_freq, na.rm = TRUE)))

# A tibble: 610 × 9
# Groups:   rsid [10]
   rsid  study                       population       group      sample_size ref_allele alt_allele         alt_freq        sdev
   <chr> <chr>                       <chr>            <chr>            <dbl> <chr>      <chr>                 <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 rs10  TopMed                      Global           Study-wide      264690 A=0.036027 C=0.963973         0.963973  0.06598503
 2 rs10  14KJPN                      JAPANESE         Study-wide       28258 A=0.00014  C=0.99986          0.99986   0.06598503
 3 rs10  8.3KJPN                     JAPANESE         Study-wide       16758 A=0.00018  C=0.99982          0.99982   0.06598503
 4 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator Total            Global            8536 A=0.0750   C=0.9250, T=0.0000 0.925    NA         
 5 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator European         Sub               7346 A=0.0826   C=0.9174, T=0.0000 0.9174   NA         
 6 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator African          Sub                676 A=0.006    C=0.994, T=0.000   0.994    NA         
 7 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator Other            Sub                484 A=0.052    C=0.948, T=0.000   0.948    NA         
 8 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator Latin American 2 Sub                 10 A=0.4      C=0.6, T=0.0       0.6      NA         
 9 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator Latin American 1 Sub                  8 A=0.0      C=1.0, T=0.0       1        NA         
10 rs10  Allele Frequency Aggregator Asian            Sub                  8 A=0.0      C=1.0, T=0.0       1        NA         
# ℹ 600 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows


Create the sample size groups (ssgp) first (0-100, 101-1000, >1000) and then group_by(rsid, ssgp). No need for case_when

I want to avoid creating additional groups.

Could you add that to your question, in addition to any other conditions, and please provide a working example of your data. See [MRE].

Your issue is related to 'timing' i.e. how case_when works, it is greedy and fully evaluates the right side values, then looks at the left side condition to see if to return them or not. This leads to your issue.
Here is a walkthrough and suggested solution (which uses temporary groupings)
library(tidyverse)

(smalldata <- data.frame(rsid=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3)),alt_freq = (1:6)^2,sample_size=rep(c(100,1),3)))

# without looking at sample size
smalldata |> group_by(rsid) |> mutate(sdev = sd(alt_freq))
# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   rsid [2]
# rsid alt_freq sample_size  sdev
# <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1        1         100  4.04
# 2     1        4           1  4.04
# 3     1        9         100  4.04
# 4     2       16           1 10.0 
# 5     2       25         100 10.0 
# 6     2       36           1 10.0 

# notice the 4.04 ; 
# sd(c(1,4,9)) 
# 4.04

# using samplesize in your style
smalldata |> group_by(rsid) |> mutate(sdev = case_when(sample_size >= 10 ~ sd(alt_freq, na.rm = TRUE)))
# Groups:   rsid [2]
# rsid alt_freq sample_size  sdev
# <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1        1         100  4.04
# 2     1        4           1 NA   
# 3     1        9         100  4.04
# 4     2       16           1 NA   
# 5     2       25         100 10.0 
# 6     2       36           1 NA   

# you have the same 4.04 because of timing, case_when evaluates sd first and then checks sample_size for if to return the sd result or NA


# how I suggest you use sample_size
smalldata |> group_by(rsid) |> mutate(use_sample = ifelse(sample_size >= 10,1,NA)) |>
  group_by(rsid,use_sample) |> mutate(sdev =  sd(use_sample * alt_freq, na.rm = TRUE)) |> group_by(rsid) |> select(-use_sample)

# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   rsid [2]
# rsid alt_freq sample_size  sdev
# <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1        1         100  5.66
# 2     1        4           1 NA   
# 3     1        9         100  5.66
# 4     2       16           1 NA   
# 5     2       25         100 NA   
# 6     2       36           1 NA  

#notice the expected result is there 
# sd(c(1,9)) 
# 5.66


Yes, it seems "timing" is the keyword that leads to unexpected result. Hope there is an elegant way without creating a temporary grouping. @hadley
